# How to enable eTag in embedded jetty server

Tags: jetty, embedded-jetty

Is there support for etags available in embedded jetty server? Should we have custom filter implementation for achieving it or do we have the support already in built?

Answer (score 2):

ETags are not supported in released versions of Jetty.

However, the next releases of [Jetty will have support for ETag](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=393947) (due out soon).

Look for versions ***after***...

- Jetty 7.6.8
- Jetty 8.1.8
- Jetty 9.0.0.M4

Answer (score 0):

I found this custom filter, will try it in a project now http://candrews.integralblue.com/2009/02/http-caching-header-aware-servlet-filter/

Answer (score 0):

From https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/javadoc/9.4.12.v20180830/org/eclipse/jetty/servlet/DefaultServlet.html :

The following initParameters are supported, these can be set either on the servlet itself or as ServletContext initParameters with a prefix of org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.Default.

`etags`             If True, weak etags will be handled.

Comment: this link is alive: http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/servlet/DefaultServlet.html